# AWS Centos 6.7 cron job scrapy crawl not working

Tags: python, linux, bash, amazon-web-services, cron

I have this following bash script in an AWS Centos instance:

scrape.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin:/myproject

cd /
cd /myproject

source env/bin/activate

scrapy crawl my_spider -o "/path/to/json/folder/my.json" -t json
```

This script works when I manually type: (the bash script is also in my project folder)

```
sh /myproject/scrape.sh
```

But my crontab job doesn't work... I've looked through every suggestion but it still doesn't work

```
0 * * * * sh /myproject/scrape.sh
```

Comment: Have you tried to redirect script output to a file and analyze it? : `0 * * * * sh /myproject/scrape.sh > /myproject/scrape.out`

Comment: I just did that and all that happened was an empty file. No text

Comment: Sorry, correction for the first comment: try with `0 * * * * sh /myproject/scrape.sh &> /myproject/scrape.out`

Comment: Check to make sure you need no other environment variables. Lastly, do

``0 * * * * sh /myproject/scrape.sh >/var/log/scrape 2>&1``

Comment: I'm a novice with linux. What do you mean by environment variables? The commands in the bash script are what I use to get scrapy to crawl, I feel like it should have the same result.

Comment: @MarcYoung Thank you for the suggestion. It helped me figure out the error: ImportError: libpython2.7.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory. I added "export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH" to the bash script to fix the error and got the cron job to work.